# automating table creation in microsoft access 2010

Tags: ms-access, ms-office, ms-access-2010

I need to design several database using Microsoft Access 2010. Because several of these databases will use the same column names and datatypes, I want to automate the table creation process as much as possible. How can I accomplish this goal with a minimum of effort?

Answer (score 0):

`DoCmd.CopyObject, "Employees Copy", acTable, "Employees"` will copy a table called Employees to a table called Employees Copy

Answer (score 0):

Or just use copy and paste, click on a table then ctrl-c, ctrl-v. choose to copy structure only then modify it accordingly.